# HDFS tiny files

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I have a source with many many tiny files (KBs) and some moderate files (1 mb to 5 mb) and a few large files (greater than 50 MB)

Now there is a choice of putting these in HDFS (merge files) or HBase (as MOBs). Which is a recommended method as far as performance of ingestion and showing files to end user is concerned?

Comment: Could you merge the small file. What the small files use for? `MR`?

Comment: Yes I could merge but if the user asks for one of those small files then will I be able to show that particular small file by pulling it out of the merged big file?  Small files are created at source outside of the system, so can't control at source

Answer (score 0):

You could put that files into HDFS. But before putting in HDFS you could merge the files by running a MR job with identitymapper and identityreducer by setting number of reducers as per your file size and block size or process it with combinefileinputformat and place it in HDFS.

Comment: Thanks. If those are merged,  will it be possible to randomly access one of the small files and show the user for downloading the file?

Comment: Nope i guess, because that is the idea behind it, with small files we have to reduce the namenode metadata overhead so we are merging it and giving a single filename to the namenode to reduce its overhead.